# python creating a list from two other lists, that only include unique items

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to write a function that takes in two lists, 
and for each item in the first list, looks into the second list, and  compares each 
item in the first list with each item in the second list. It needs to return a new list containing the all 
items that do not appear in first list.

So for instance, given a list:

```
list1 = ['yellow', 'blue', 'green']
```

and the second list:

```
list2 = ['orange', 'green', 'blue', 'pink', 'yellow']
```

it should return a list of only the items in list2 that are not in list1, like this:

```
['orange', 'pink']
```

I have written many functions but they keep returning duplicates, I really appreciate any help on this!

```
def different_colors(list1, list2):
    newlist = []

    for color in list1:
        newlist = [] 
        for color2 in list2:
            if color1 != color2:
                newlist.append(color2)

    return newlist
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use Python sets.

```
>>> list1 = ['yellow', 'blue', 'green']
>>> list2 = ['orange', 'green', 'blue', 'pink', 'yellow']
>>> list(set(list2).difference(set(list1)))
['orange', 'pink']
```

[Python sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) are about manipulating collections of unique elements. They have specific methods for this purpose.

Comment: Gah. This is almost the answer (sets are perfect), except I don't see why you think he wants a `symmetric_difference`: he only wants a one-way difference, no? (Sadly, his example passes your code.)

Comment: That's true, I didn't read the question properly. Edited to swap list1, and list2 and just get the difference.

Comment: And now you've got my +1. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[k for k in dictionary.keys() if k not in listt]
```

Comment: Your example doesn't relate to the question at all. `[colour for colour in list2 if colour not in list1]` is more relevant.